# How to download grails zip file from github

Tags: java, github, grails

i want to download grails by this link . This link show a zip file from Github. but i try to download multiple time by useing Firefox, Opera, and FMD5 Download manager

```
https://github.com/grails/grails-core/releases/download/v3.3.10/grails-3.3.10.zip
```

but every case after download 20%-30% show download failed massage.

***can any one help me for Download this file or Download Grails***

[Grails Ref link](https://grails.org/download.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending long time for Google search I solve my problem...

***Unfortunately this problem raise from my PC and Internet connection.*** After change net connection and using another Desktop I download this file successfully.

thank you everyone......